# How to disable Unity chameleon effect?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the Unity launcher chameleon effect?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect)

New unity feature changes the colour of the launcher and notifications that matches them to the wallpaper. For me it's EXTREMELY ANNOYING! External apps like MyUnity doesn't solve this problem. When I change color in MyUnity it works till i close app, then it's revert to previous color.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Yes, it is a problem that's being parsed through. Please see the link above,