# Launcher and dash has a red tint after update to 12.04

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, colors

I just updated to 12.04, and the launcher looks like it has a more redish color than it used to, I checked the "online tour" of 12.04, and the launcher there seems to be more to the violet end of the spectrum. The dash also seems to have this effect. At first boot i got an error where something called colord had failed. Everything else appear to be normal.

I am using a nvidia gtx 560 ti card, am I supposed to mess around in nvidia settings and find some color settings there? 
It seems strange that it's only the launcher that is behaving this way. 
Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I have set the opacity of the top panel manually, it's not a bug.

[image: Picture]

Comment: are you sure you are not just seeing the new "chameleon" feature where the launcher matches the wallpaper?

Comment: Check this out if you want to disable "chemeleon" effect http://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect

Comment: Seems like it is that I'm experiencing! When changing backgrounds, the color changes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

What you are seeing is actually the new chameleon feature in Unity

*the animated gif doesnt really give justice to this!*

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I disable the chameleon effect in notifications and the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect)