# Launcher makes no colored in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the Unity launcher chameleon effect?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect)

The pitcher does not provide color after removing configuration window.
Here a video to show:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-xmRHOYNxE&feature=youtu.be