# Can't change the Dash Color

Tags: unity, 12.04, 64-bit, unity-dash, colors

I try to change the Dash color from CCSM or MyUnity but I after I choose a color it changes to the default by it self in 2-3 seconds.

using unity 5.12.0

Comment: Possible solutions - http://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect/127768#127768

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in 12.04 as stated here https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/975350

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu tweak offers the capability to change the color of your dash

To install

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update sudo
>
> apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

---

[image]

Comment: my Ubuntu Tweak looks different -http://i.imgur.com/Nc21J.png

Comment: @Tosho Same here! Please update the answer as it seems it's not applicable to Ubuntu 12.04.