# How can foreground and background colors be changed for Software Center?

Tags: software-center, customization, accessibility

There sometimes isn't enough contrast between the letters and background, and I have reached an age that I can't tell what's there. I would prefer either black text on white background, or white text on a black background. Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Hello, please ask one question at a time. I have removed the "dash" part of your question. How to change the color of the Dash Home is covered [**in this question here**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119731). If that isn't what you're looking for, please open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130031/cant-change-the-dash-color

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ubuntu Tweak. You can find it in the repository, and you may find other tweak software.

Another approach would be to can change the theme you are working in.