# Compiz - green transparent textures?

Tags: unity, compiz

Unity dash, launcher and notifications goes green after a short moment after login.
That happened here:

[image]

I use the fglrx driver on my ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 series graphics card.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Unity has an effect, known as 'chameleon effect'
According to this answer: [How do I disable the chameleon effect in notifications and the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect) there isn't an easy way to turn off this effect.

Specifically, Unity takes similar color to your desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 11.10 it can be done with an application called MyUnity.

In Ubuntu 12.04, though, the only way I know to disable this beheaviour is to switch to Unity 2D, and use [this (alpha-stage) application](http://robinj.be/unity-2d-config-util/#dash#home) to choose a static colour you like.
To run this application you will need `mono-runtime`. To change the background colours, you need to run the application as root. Other settings you change while running as root will not apply to the current user though, which is a bug. In case things get messy, it always leave a backup of system files that where changed by the application.

---

I am the maker of the application I referenced to, so if you find any bugs (likely you will), feel free to report them to me (preferably on the Launchpad page, so I can keep track of things).