# Chameleon effect not working after update

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 since it came out and so far didn't have any problems with it. But after I updated (via Update Manager) it yesterday, after every reboot, the launcher color defaults to a blue dash, workspace and trash icon and the rest is black. If I set the wallpaper again manually, then it changes color as its supposed to (chameleon).

Any idea why this is? Its really annoying to change your wallpaper every time you logon just to get the "normal" launcher.

**EDIT**

The chameleon effect works perfectly for notifications. Only the Launcher and Dash are not changing the color.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any themes?

Comment: @Mitch Nope, I haven't made any customizations. Its just stock Ubuntu

Comment: You may refer to this page:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-launcher-chameleon-effect

Comment: @Linuxthink Actually, its the other way around. I _want_ the chameleon effect. I'm not just getting it currently.

Comment: Same problem here. If I change the wallpaper, it goes back to normal

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).