# Turn off chameleonic notification color

Tags: unity, notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the chameleon effect in notifications and the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-disable-the-chameleon-effect-in-notifications-and-the-unity-launcher)

I would like to be able to turn off the chameleonic background color for Notify OSD, preferably programmatically (through dconf or something). I can't seem to find a specific dconf key for it, and I don't have Unity installed.

Comment: Have you seen this? <http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html> If you're asking for a cli way, I'm sorry but I don't know