# How to disable chameleon effect in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the chameleon effect in notifications and the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-disable-the-chameleon-effect-in-notifications-and-the-unity-launcher)

Well, there was MyUnity in 12.04 for this. But what should I do now? I want black or gray Dash and Notifycations, not orange or green.