# The dash home button icon is an unexpected colour since upgrading. Why?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

Simple question. My dash home icon is yellow since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, even after a reboot.

It looks weird to me. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dash icon and app lenses do follow the main color of your desktop image. Unity has this behavior since 12.04. 
Is the dominant color of your desktop yellow?

Comment: Oh I see. My background's dominant colour does not appear to be yellow, but apparently it appears to be to ubuntu. It looked out of place because the left edge is nealy completely black.

Comment: It's called Chameleon effect. Here is some discussion about removing it, it seems not that easy to turn off. [How do I disable the chameleon effect in notifications and the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119731/how-do-i-disable-the-chameleon-effect-in-notifications-and-the-unity-launcher)