# Unity Launch Button Changes Color in 14.04- Why?

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, menu

I just noticed for the first time that the Ubuntu's "Start Button" equivalent can be different colors. Yesterday I had to take a screenshot to debug something, and the button was blue. But today it's green.

What does this signify? Also, what are the approprate terms for the launcher, 'start button' etc so I can do a better google search on the issue next time?

Comment: It changes colour according to the background. Did you change the background? The thing that opens up when you click on it is called the Dash, so the Dash button seems appropriate. http://askubuntu.com/questions/203807/the-dash-home-button-icon-is-an-unexpected-colour-since-upgrading-why

Comment: I didn't change the background, but when it was green I did have an external monitor attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the button color is based on your desktop wallpaper, you can try to fix it by changing the wallpaper and then be back on the one you like.

P.S. The true name is "dash button".